# BitmapDecoder がサポートしている画像ファイルの種類(拡張子)を全て取得したい

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Windows10、VisualStudio2015、.Net4.6、WPF、C# で開発しております。

System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.Create() で読み込める画像ファイルの種類とその拡張子を取得する方法はありますでしょうか？

デジカメの画像ファイル(.CR2)とか読み込めるのですが、関数リファレンスからはサポートされているという情報を見つけられませんでした。OS依存かもしれませんので、コードで取得する方法を探しております。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BitmapDecoder`はWindows Imaging Componentというフレームワークに登録されたコーデックを利用しています。なので対応しているフォーマットはOSのバージョン依存というよりは、インストールしているソフトによって変動します。

WICに追加されたコーデックはレジストリの`CLSID\{7ED96837-96F0-4812-B211-F13C24117ED3}`(WICBitmapDecoders)以下にCLSIDが登録されており、各クラスの配下に`FileExtensions`が登録されているので、それらの値から拡張子が取得できます。

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // WICBitmapDecodersの一覧を開く
    var decoders = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{7ED96837-96F0-4812-B211-F13C24117ED3}\Instance");
    foreach (var clsId in decoders.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(clsId);

        // コーデックのレジストリを開く
        var codec = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\CLSID\" + clsId);

        Console.WriteLine(codec.GetValue("FriendlyName"));
        Console.WriteLine(codec.GetValue("FileExtensions"));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

またJPEGやPNGといったOSネイティブのコーデック(7種類)は上記には登録されていません。なのでこれらに対しては実際にファイルを開いて情報を取得するのが良いのではないでしょうか。

```
foreach (var fn in new[] { "dummy.jpg" })
    // TODO:bmp, gif, ico, jpg, png, tiff, wmpに対して行う
{
    var dec = BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri(Path.GetFullPath(fn)), BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);

    Console.WriteLine(dec.GetType());
    Console.WriteLine(dec.CodecInfo.FriendlyName);
    Console.WriteLine(dec.CodecInfo.FileExtensions);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: .dds も扱えるのですが、レジストリからの情報にはありませんでした。こちらの情報の取得方法は分かりますでしょうか。

Comment: @nee 通常`BitmapDecoder.Create`で.ddsファイルを読み込むことはできないように思います。.ddsについてはWPF以外のライブラリを使用しているのであれば当然標準的な方法でコーデックを得ることはできませんので、独自に対応してください。

Comment: 購入直後でOfficeを導入しただけのWindows10PCで試したところ、.ddsが読み込めることを確認しました。 やはりレジストリからは取得できておりません。実際にファイルを開いて取得した情報は次の通りです。  
    `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.UnknownBitmapDecoder`  
    `DDS Decoder`  
    `.dds`  
こちらの情報でなにか分かりますでしょうか。

Comment: @nee [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424129.aspx)の別のページではWICのネイティブコーデックに9種類あげられていて、DDSについては90種類のうち3形式をサポートしているとのことです。