# BitmapDecoder がサポートしている画像ファイルの種類(拡張子)を全て取得したい (.heicとか)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

環境
Windows10 64bit April 2018 Update
VisualStudio 2017
.Net Framework 4.6.2
WPF

[HEIF Image Extensions](https://www.microsoft.com/ja-jp/p/heif-image-extensions/9pmmsr1cgpwg) をインストールすることで .heic 画像ファイルもデコードできるようになったのですが、以前解決した方法([BitmapDecoder がサポートしている画像ファイルの種類(拡張子)を全て取得したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/23202/bitmapdecoder-%E3%81%8C%E3%82%B5%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AE%E7%A8%AE%E9%A1%9E%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E5%AD%90%E3%82%92%E5%85%A8%E3%81%A6%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84))では、この拡張子が取得できません。

ストアからインストールしてデコードできるようになった画像の拡張子も取得したいのですが、どのようにすればよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C#で実装するには必要な情報が提供されていません。Windows SDKに含まれているC++ヘッダーファイル `wincodec.h` の情報が必要です。

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <wrl/client.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wincodec.h>
template<class T> using ComPtr = Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<T>;

void check(HRESULT hr) { if (FAILED(hr)) throw hr; }

int main() {
    struct Com {
        Com() { check(CoInitialize(nullptr)); }
        ~Com() { CoUninitialize(); }
    } com;
    ComPtr<IWICImagingFactory> imageingFactory;
    check(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WICImagingFactory, nullptr, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&imageingFactory)));
    ComPtr<IEnumUnknown> enumUnknown;
    check(imageingFactory->CreateComponentEnumerator(WICDecoder, WICComponentEnumerateDefault, &enumUnknown));
    for (ComPtr<IUnknown> unknown; enumUnknown->Next(1, &unknown, nullptr) == S_OK;) {
        ComPtr<IWICBitmapCodecInfo> codecInfo;
        check(unknown.As(&codecInfo));
        wchar_t friendlyName[1024], fileExtensions[1024];
        UINT actual;
        check(codecInfo->GetFriendlyName(static_cast<UINT>(std::size(friendlyName)), friendlyName, &actual));
        check(codecInfo->GetFileExtensions(static_cast<UINT>(std::size(fileExtensions)), fileExtensions, &actual));
        std::wcout << friendlyName << L": " << fileExtensions << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

実行するとこんな感じで、レジストリでは得られなかったコーデックについてもリストされます。

```
BMP Decoder: .bmp,.dib,.rle
GIF Decoder: .gif
ICO Decoder: .ico,.icon
JPEG Decoder: .jpeg,.jpe,.jpg,.jfif,.exif
PNG Decoder: .png
TIFF Decoder: .tiff,.tif
DNG Decoder: .dng
WMPhoto Decoder: .wdp,.jxr
DDS Decoder: .dds
Microsoft HEIF Decoder: .heic,.heif,.heics,.avcs,.heifs
Microsoft Camera Raw Decoder: .ARW,.CR2,.CRW,.ERF,.KDC,.MRW,.NEF,.NRW,.ORF,.PEF,.RAF,.RAW,.RW2,.RWL,.SR2,.SRW,.DNG
```

挙げたコードはもちろんC++言語ですが、C#言語に移植するのは大変なのでやめておきます。

Comment: C#からはDLL化してPInvoke呼び出しを行うことで実装できそうです。ありがとうございました。